# How can I center a <div>

Tags: css, html

I currently have this div:

```
<div style="background: lightsalmon;margin-bottom: 12px; width: 600px; padding: 5px 8px;border: 1px solid #071B36;border-radius: 3px;">
    TEST
</div>
```

---

I have tried using `<div style="text-align:center;"> </div>` like this:

```
<div style='text-align: center;'>
    <div style="background: lightsalmon;margin-bottom: 12px; width: 600px; padding: 5px 8px;border: 1px solid #071B36;border-radius: 3px;">
        TEST
    </div>
</div>
```

**^ Doesn't work**

---

I've also tried using `<div style="text-align:center; display:block;"> </div>` like this:

```
<div style='text-align: center;  display:block;'>
    <div style="background: lightsalmon;margin-bottom: 12px; width: 600px; padding: 5px 8px;border: 1px solid #071B36;border-radius: 3px;">
        TEST
    </div>
</div>
```

**^ Doesn't work**

---

I've also tried using `<center> </center>` (even though it is not recommended...

```
<center>
    <div style="background: lightsalmon;margin-bottom: 12px; width: 600px; padding: 5px 8px;border: 1px solid #071B36;border-radius: 3px;">
        TEST
    </div>
</center>
```

**^ It works!!!**

---

**The only problem is that `<center>` is terrible to use as it is outdated! So how can I do this without using `<center>`**

Comment: Please do a search.  Certainly you didn't believe you were the first person in the history of SO to want to center a DIV.

Comment: A `<div>` is a block level element, unaffected by `text-align`. They can be center-aligned using `margin:auto`. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/v6Uec/)

Answer (score -1):

is this what you want to achieve?
http://jsfiddle.net/cancerian73/LUcUZ/

```
<div style="background: lightsalmon;margin-bottom: 12px; width: 600px; padding: 5px 8px;border: 1px solid #071B36;border-radius: 3px; margin:0 auto;">
    TEST
</div>
```